# How to make buttons stay fixed at the bottom while scrolling

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.

The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom
[image]

```css
  .fix-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

  .d-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-bottom btn-shadow ">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <button ion-button full (click)="addToCartProduct()" style="width: 50%; height: 45px;background-color: #3498db">ADD TO CART</button>
    <button ion-button full style="width: 50%; height: 45px;background-color: #f53d3d;" (click)="proceedToCheckOut()">BUY NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you writing you css like "fix-bottom : .fix-bottom"? What is the purpose? Does it even work? Why do you have inline styling in your html?

Comment: Fixed items belong outside `</ion-content>`.

Comment: @Wimanicesir about the css,  i am sorry , quite new to all of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put your button in bottom of the page then, You need to put your button in **ion-footer** like this way

```
 <ion-content>.... </ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <button ion-button full (click)="addToCartProduct()" style="width: 50%; height: 45px;background-color: #3498db">ADD
    TO CART</button>
  <button ion-button full style="width: 50%; height: 45px;background-color: #f53d3d;" (click)="proceedToCheckOut()">BUY
    NOW</button>
</ion-footer>
```

I have tried your code in this template and it's working.so please try this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example. When you scroll to the up the button stays bottom fixed. It's simple css. I've add paragraph many times just to show scrolling effect.

```css
#bottom button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 1000;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.basicimage(rotation=3);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.
</p>
<p>The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom 
I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.</p>

<p>The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom 
I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.</p>

<p>The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom 
I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.</p>

<p>The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom
I am quite new to ionic, html and css. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button stay fixed when scrolling the page. Somehow the button does not stay fixed even when I state fixed value on css.

The button somehow does not stay fixed at the bottom </p>
<div id="bottom">
    <button id="bot_open" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">Button</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: i am sorry but this suggestion not working in my project

Comment: Hi @FirdausIsmail i already saw that someone answered right answer. So i want to give you this example so that it might help you in the future.